# Pandas insert row into dataframe with timezone-aware index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe that has a timezone-aware index, and when I try to insert a new row into this dataframe, it doesn't work, instead changing the type of the index to `'object'` (ie, it can't add in the row into the current type).

MRE below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"time": ["2021/06/06 12:00:00"], "col1": [2]})
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.drop('time', axis=1)
df.index = df.index.tz_localize('UTC')

# Doesn't work, index is now 'object' as this is considered a string
# row = pd.Series(name='2021/06/05 12:00:00')
# df = df.append(row)


# Also doesn't work, as timezones differ
row = pd.Series(name=pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00'))
df = df.append(row)

print(df.index)
```

I understand I can do the following:

```
tz = df.index[0].tz
row = pd.Series(name=pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz=tz))
```

However I'm sceptical of whether this would work when the units differ, or maybe even some other property of a pandas `Timestamp` I don't know of, so would ideally like to completely copy over the `Timestamp` configuration of the index to the new timestamp I'm inserting.

If anyone would happen to know how to insert a new row into this dataframe whilst keeping the index type intact that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not assign `tz`in `Timestamp`: `pd.Series(name=pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz = "UTC"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`DatetimeTZ`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeTZDtype.html) only supports a single timezone, the key is to make sure the new [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) always matches your existing `df.index.tz`.

When inserting a new [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html):

- Use `tz=df.index.tz` if it's from the same time zone
- Use [`astimezone(df.index.tz)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.astimezone.html) if it's from a different time zone

---

#### Examples

- Given your MRE `df`:

  ```
  df
  #                            col1
  # time                           
  # 2021-06-06 12:00:00+00:00     2

  df.index.dtype
  # datetime64[ns, UTC]
  ```
- If you know your new [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) is in the same `tz`, just set it in the constructor like you mentioned:

  ```
  ts1 = pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz=df.index.tz)
  df.loc[ts1] = 4
  #                            col1
  # time                           
  # 2021-06-06 12:00:00+00:00     2
  # 2021-06-05 12:00:00+00:00     4

  df.index.dtype
  # datetime64[ns, UTC]
  ```
- If your new [`Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) is in a different `tz` (which was your main concern), convert it using [`astimezone`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.astimezone.html) (e.g., from Eastern US back to UTC):

  ```
  ts2 = pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz='US/Eastern').astimezone(df.index.tz)
  df.loc[ts2] = 6
  #                            col1
  # time                           
  # 2021-06-06 12:00:00+00:00     2
  # 2021-06-05 12:00:00+00:00     4
  # 2021-06-05 16:00:00+00:00     6

  df.index.dtype
  # datetime64[ns, UTC]
  ```
- Note that I'm using [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) because it's faster and simpler, but [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) still works:

  ```
  ts3 = pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz='US/Central').astimezone(df.index.tz)
  row = pd.Series([8], name=ts3, index=['col1'])
  df = df.append(row)
  #                            col1
  # time                           
  # 2021-06-06 12:00:00+00:00     2
  # 2021-06-05 12:00:00+00:00     4
  # 2021-06-05 16:00:00+00:00     6
  # 2021-06-05 17:00:00+00:00     8

  df.index.dtype
  # datetime64[ns, UTC]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`Timestamp` objects are certainly of type `'object'`, and it is possible you cannot escape the index to take this type if you use `Timestamp`s as index.

By "timestamp configuration" I understand "timezone", and that you want to insert new times in the same timezone.

- Either you know the timezone from the start and data of all rows come from a source known to be from the same timezone. In that case you can specify the same timezone when you instantiate the `Timestamp`s.
- Or you do not know the timezone of the data in the first place, and you have new data coming from another source, so potentially from a different timezone, that you certainly know about. Mixing timestamps from different timezones is not a problem, since timezones should be taken into account when you compare them with one another. You can still localize them all later to a timezone you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this. `DateTimeIndexes` are objects.

```
for time_zone in ['MST', 'EST', 'GMT']:
        row = pd.Timestamp('2021/06/05 12:00:00', tz=time_zone)
        df.loc[row] = 1

# to whichever timezone you want
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, utc=True).tz_convert('EST')
```